# Efficient method to pick random point

Tags: random

SETUP:

I have a file which contains a list of points each with a specific (X, Y) location. Something that looks a bit like

```
3.8474 4.4847
8.3746 2.4829
...
2.4583 6.2848
```

These points are all contained in some rectangle of an unknown size before reading the file. The bounds of the rectangle containing these points is defined by the finding the min and max X values and min and max Y values from all the points on the list.

PROBLEM:

I want to choose a random point inside this bounding rectangle which is at least some distance `A` away from the edge of the bounding rectangle. I then want to find all the points in the rectangle which are less than a distance `A` away from this random point.

ATTEMPTED SOLUTION:

My issue with this is that in order to choose a random point a certain distance from the edge, I need to know that edge first. That requires reading in every single point and finding the min and max X and Y values. I then have to read each of the points a second time to find which ones are less than a distance `A` away from my randomly chosen position. Reading the list twice seems to be wildly inefficient, especially if the list contains a million points or more. But I can't think of a more efficient way to do it. I need to at least read in the data once and I could store it in an array for the second round of reading, but setting aside the memory space for a million element array seems excessive as well. Any suggestions?

Comment: I can't see any other way either. I think you should try first and see how the tradeoff looks like, if this is going to be a real problem in terms of memory or in terms of time.

Comment: What code have you written? What results has it produced? What results did you expect? Questions about general approach are better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ than StackOverflow.

Comment: @Leo That is my concern. This could become a memory issue so I may just have to read the file twice.

Comment: @zephyr well, my rule of thumb is: time is easier to fix than memory :-) if you think your dataset can grow from millions to billions, than probably your memory problem will be the most important, so you'll have to scan the files several times (or even import into some DB, etc). But if a million performs ok and it's near the worst case and if speed is more important and there are not too many users using the system at the same time, than keep arrays in memory and go ahead. Probably, your client can accept waiting for a result than having no result at all

Comment: @Leo Thanks for your help. I'll just have to go with this solution, even though it isn't as efficient as I would like.

Comment: if there isn't any other way, then your solution is the best one ;-)

Comment: Could you leverage the logic of the [German tank problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) to estimate the rectangle bounds based on a reasonably sized random sample of the points? This gives an unbiased estimate of the bound with variability that decreases exponentially with the sample size, so even with sample sizes of a few hundred or a few thousand out of your population of a million values you should do quite well.